# TinyMce Editor How to delete div tags

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc, tinymce

when l do copy paste on tinymce editor. tinymce is adding div tags automatically
how can l stop this  l will give you an example

l want to add a paragraph like this;
Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500'lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinle

normally it should be like this

```
<p>
Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500'lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinle
</p>
```

but when l try to do copy paste program creates a div and paragraph  automatically going inside a div like this

```
<div>
<p>
Lorem Ipsum, dizgi ve baskı endüstrisinde kullanılan mıgır metinlerdir. Lorem Ipsum, adı bilinmeyen bir matbaacının bir hurufat numune kitabı oluşturmak üzere bir yazı galerisini alarak karıştırdığı 1500'lerden beri endüstri standardı sahte metinle
</p>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are copy/pasting content into the editor the first thing you should do is identify what data is being placed in the clipboard by the source application. These simple pages can show you what is being placed in the clipboard:

- (IE11 / Edge) http://static.ephox.com/clipboard/clipboardtestms.html
- (All browsers not named IE11 or Edge) http://static.ephox.com/clipboard/clipboardtest.html

If the source app is placing a p inside a div then the editor is simply bringing over the data its given and that would be the expected behavior.

Comment: I need a code for blocking divs l searched alot but l couldnt find if you know any code to block divs please let me know
 I need to write a code in tinymce_fullcompressed file